# Output exact depth map in Blender

Tags: blender

How can I output the depth information of each frame in blender to a `.txt` file?

I can generate a depth-map as gray-scale image with values in **[0,1]** but I want the values in units I use in Blender (*meter* in my case).

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be very easy. Just link the `Z buffer` in the `Node Editor` with the output. Also make sure to turn he `Z buffer` on.